# UML implements relationship in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am using draw.io. I can see an "extends" UML arrow.  I can't see an "implements" one.  This should have a dash lined and arrow at the end.

**Is** there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

draw.io doesn't provide every single variation of shape/connector decoration, but you can configure existing shapes/connectors.

In your case, select the line and in the right-hand format panel look in the "style" tab. There you have options to change the line type (to dashed in your case) and the line start and end decorations.

[image: The style panel for a connector in draw.io]

So that you don't have to configure shapes and connectors that you use frequently, draw.io supports a [scratchpad](https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/scratchpad) for quick re-use and it supports [custom libraries](https://www.diagrams.net/blog/custom-libraries) of shapes and edges.